# JavaScript workaround for not supported HTML5 elements and attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr

I am using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect unsupported HTML5 elements and attributes within browsers. If a element/attribute is not supported I like to write a quick workaround with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

At the moment I am stumbling around the "required" attribute with input element. My thought was to "detect" the associated form element and hook the jQuery [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event of the form. **But how to do it?**

To gain insight yourself here is a sample code how I fixed the "placeholder" attribute with input element:

```
if(Modernizr.input.placeholder == false) {
    alert('input placeholder not exists, perform a workaround...');
    $('[placeholder]').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var placeholder = input.attr('placeholder');
        input.bind('focus', function() {
            if(this.value == placeholder) {
                this.value = '';
                $(this).removeClass('mzr-no-placeholder');
            }
        }).bind('blur', function() {
            if(this.value == '') {
                this.value = placeholder;
                $(this).addClass('mzr-no-placeholder');
            }
        });
        if(!this.value.length) {
            this.value = placeholder;
            $(this).addClass('mzr-no-placeholder');
        }
    });
}
else {
    alert('input placeholder exists.');
}
```

## Here is the solution

Thanks to greut.

```
if(Modernizr.input.required == false) {
    alert('Tag input required not exists, perform a workaround...');
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var requirementsOK = true;
        $('[required]', this).each(function() {
            if(!this.value.length) {
                $(this).addClass('mzr-no-required');
                requirementsOK = false;
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('mzr-no-required');
            }
        });
        return requirementsOK;
    });
}
else {
    alert('Tag input required exists.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an hint on how to start that:

```
if (Modernizer.input.required === false) {
    $('form').submit(function() {
         $('[required]', this).each(function() {
              if (!$(this).val()) {
                  alert('derp!');
                  return false;
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the cart before the horse... The best solutions always those I don't keep in mind. Thanks, @greut